# Python path separator

Tags: python, path

Is there a proper platform-dependent (or independent?) path separator character somewhere in the Python standard library?

I am not asking about the *directory* separator `/` and `\`, but rather about the `PATH` separator: `:` and `;`.

Java has [`java.io.File.pathSeparatorChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar) and [`java.io.File.pathSeparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator) to fulfill this need. Does Python have something similar? A fairly exhaustive search in [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) and [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) docs yielded nothing, so I am beginning to lose hope.

I am not particularly hung up on the character itself. A function that behaves like [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) but for entire paths instead of path elements would be perfectly acceptable, preferable even.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
import os

os.pathsep
```

[`os.pathsep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pathsep) is `:` or `;` while [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep) is `\` or `/`.